# WPF ListView DoubleClick OriginalSource problem

Tags: wpf, listview, click, double-click, listviewitem

I attached an `EventHandler` to the `MouseDoubleClick` event.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyle}">                                
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
</Style>

private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {}
```

The `ListView`'s View is based on the `GridView`, one of the column contains a `CheckBox`.
I want to be able to **ignore the double click** if the `CheckBox` is double-clicked.

The problem is that **I cannot find the original source (CheckBox)** to block it, as with routing event I got the `Theme` as the original source, and with direct I got the `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to find out if any ancestor of the OriginalSource is a CheckBox like this:

```
private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

    // suppress event?
    if (IsWithinCheckBox(obj))
        return;

    // handle your event here
}

private bool IsWithinCheckBox(DependencyObject obj)
{
    while (obj != null)
    {
        if (obj is CheckBox)
            return true;

        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }

    return false;
}
```